# iAd banner moves entire SKScene upwards. Swift Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, iad

I created this game in sprite kit and added a banner to the GameViewController. When the banner appears though the entire SKScene Menu moves a bit upwards instead of the banner going over the scene when it gets loaded. This is my code.

How can I make it so that the scene doesn't move at all?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Presenting scene without using GameScene.sks
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    let myScene = Menu(size: skView.frame.size)
    skView.presentScene(myScene)
    //loadInterstitialAd()

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.bannerView?.delegate = self
    self.bannerView?.hidden = true


}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bannerView?.hidden = false
    view.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bannerView?.hidden = true
    view.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: How did you add the banner? Through code or using a storyboard?

Comment: This is the entire code that adds the banner, Its a different way of adding it. I used to do it through storyboard and different code, up until I needed it to be in landscape and then I ran unto this.